# Javascript - append returned call_id to button

Tags: javascript, html, append

Hi everyone i have a problem with opening modal with javascript. I'm trying to open modal with returned data from jquery function. I can explain with examples:

My javascript code:

```
function (data) {
$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url : '<?php echo site_url('home/check_call/'); ?>',
success : function(data){
      if (data.calls == 200 && $('#re-calling-modal').length == 0 && $('#re-talking-modal').length == 0) {
        if ($('#calling-modal').length == 0) {
          $('body').append(data.calls_html);
          if (!$('#re-calling-modal').hasClass('calling')) {
            $('#re-calling-modal').modal({
              show: true
            });
            PlayVideoCall('play');
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

and at this line appending data from response (response "calls_html" includes in_call.php modal page):

```
$('body').append(data.calls_html);
```

in_call.php file:

```
     <div class="modal-footer" >
         <button data-href="#" type="button" onclick="AnswerCall(' ###CALL ID HERE### ', '<?php echo site_url('call/'); ?> ###CALL ID HERE### ');"> Answer</button>
         <button type="button" onclick="DeclineCall(' ###CALL ID HERE### ')"> Decline</button>
     </div>
```

ajax response includes call_id. I want to apend call id to : `onclick="DeclineCall(' ###CALL ID HERE### ')"`

How can I add this?

P.S: Sorry my bad english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first make your button easier to find by adding an ID if possible. Then your success callback you can do:

```
$("button#someId").attr("onclick", "DeclineCall(' ###CALL ID HERE### ')")
```

This should set the attribute "onclick" for your button. But maybe you want to just observe the event in JS completely:

```
$("button#someId").click(function(){ DeclineCall("callid"); });
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Second one more efficienty :)